# UIImage in view not saved when taking screenshot programmatically - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to take a screenshot with:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.contentView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.contentView.bounds.size);
}

[self.contentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, the image saved does not include an image within the screenshot (shows white instead). Why is this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When are you trying to make that screenshot? Did you check the contentView bounds size?

Also, did you consider using UIView snapshot: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates

Comment: Yes I did, everything is fine. UIImage should be within bounds. I have problems using the UIView Snapshot as I need an UIImage to save to the photoalbum in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.image.bounds.size, NO, 2.0);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.image.bounds.size);
}

[self.image drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.image.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
if (imageData) {
    [imageData writeToFile:@"screenshot.png" atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSLog(@"error while taking screenshot");
}
```

Comment: Still shows white, but all other subviews are on the screenshot (a tableview, other labels and buttons), except for the image (UIImageView).

Comment: In place  of contet view put image view,check edited code

Comment: where? Before drawViewHierarchyInRect.. ?

Comment: your image view or image you can draw view.If u want to check that image put this  line   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);  and check in your photo album.

Comment: The resulted image still is white. But I need to to have a screenshot of the whole screen with the image in it. Is there maybe a problem with my view hierarchy?
view -> scrollview -> contentView -> all subviews, including imageView, buttons and labels